# Need to retain white spaces in java script

Tags: javascript, whitespace, retain

I have a query regarding java script.

I have a function addOptions

```
function addOption(selectbox,text,value )
{
    var optn = document.createElement("OPTION");    
    optn.textContent = text;
    optn.value = value;
    selectbox.options.add(optn);
}
```

in which parameter "text" contains white spaces, and when i do optn.textContent = text; those white spaces get truncated. BUt i want to retain those white spaces as this is a requirement. I tried using optn.text = text; also but not working I am using FF 3.6.25

Could anyone please help here

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried setting `innerHTML` and changing spaces into non-breaking spaces:

```
optn.innerHTML = text.replace(/\s/g,"&nbsp;");
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/eNDKv/

Comment: Of course, this will have the side effect of also parsing the input text as HTML where it previously hadn't, which may or may not be desirable with respect to HTML injection especially if the text comes from user-submitted content.

Comment: @DelanAzabani - an extra `.replace(/</g,"&lt;")` on the end should fix that if desired. (Though in Chrome when I tried embedding a `<script>` in the text of the option the JS didn't actually run.)

Answer (score 1):

```
optn.appendChild(document.createTextNode(text));
```

will work.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:

```
function addOption(selectbox,text,value )
{    
    selectbox.add(new Option(text, value), null) //add new option to end of "sample"
}
```

The above works in FireFox 12.0.

Comment: In Chrome that doesn't keep extra white space. (I haven't tested it in any other browsers.)

Comment: @nnnnnn: I have tested with Chrome 20.0.1132.27 beta-m and it does keep the embedded white spaces.

Comment: I'm running a non-beta version (19.0.1084.52), but it didn't work for me here: http://jsfiddle.net/Y4Ev4/